# Dynamic DrawerNavigator based on Login State React Native

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

I need a DrawerNavigator that shows different options if the user is logged in or logged out, which is illustrated below:

## not logged in

```
--------------------
| sign up / log in |
|------------------|
| info             |
--------------------
```

## logged in

```
--------------------
| My Account       |
|------------------|
| Some Actions     |
|------------------|
| Info             |
|------------------|
| Log Out          |
--------------------
```

I have no problem setting up a DrawerNavigator, which I use NavigationActions and Redux. However problem arises when I'm trying to display different DrawerNavigation - where should I check for the login status from Redux?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Yes, I did. I used custom content component with Redux to solve this issue. I will answer in details in the answer section shortly.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem yesterday, but I found a good example and tutorial to do this. Look at this [tutorial](https://shift.infinite.red/react-navigation-drawer-tutorial-a802fc3ee6dc), good luck! :)

Comment: the tutorial doesn't mention anything about dynamic routes !