# how to create dynamic drawer menu navigation using react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I would like to create a dynamic drawer menu navigation using react-native. All the menu items are listed from a json file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found this one to be helpful maybe give it a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48333738/dynamic-drawernavigator-based-on-login-state-react-native

Answer (score 0):

With boostrap in consideration:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            { this.state.dynamicDrawer
                &&
                    <div className="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
                    </div>
            }
        </div>
)
}
```

Then change state on open close or toggle it differently, also here you should add a class for the btn-group-vertical that makes the whole thing fixed top left 100% height and some padding or whatever you wish.

To make the list dynamic include a

```
this.state.buttons.map(button => { return (<button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">{button}</button>)})
```

Here for native some info: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/drawerlayoutandroid

```
render: function() {
  var navigationView = (
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
        { 
        this.state.dynamicTexts.map(dynamicText => { return (
          <Text style={{margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'right'}}>{]{dynamicText}</Text>
        )}
        }
    </View>
  );
  return (
    <DrawerLayoutAndroid
      drawerWidth={300}
      drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
      renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}>
      <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center'}}>
       <Text style={{margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'right'}}>Hello</Text>
       <Text style={{margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'right'}}>World!</Text>
      </View>
</DrawerLayoutAndroid>
  );
},
```

**Methods**
*openDrawer()*

```
openDrawer();
```

Opens the drawer.

*closeDrawer()*

```
closeDrawer();
```

I'm sure with these components you can build it together :)

Best of luck!

Comment: the question is about react-native

Comment: Except the styling and tags it will still work, just have to adjust it a little. Use View tags etc. and if Boostrap doesn't exist for native just create some styling, shouldn't be an issue. The technical part is the same.

Comment: Sorry I am asking about react native.

Comment: @RabithaN Yes, as you may see I have extended the answer to include react native...